# Can two data marts be entirely different from each other in spite of being (both) part of an organization?

Tags: data-warehouse

In a text book, the above mentioned line is printed. But I don't agree with it. Because if we look from top to bottom or vice versa, each business component has single business goal (and in most cases "profit"). So somewhere these data marts belonging to two different branches or organisation have something in common "business goal".

Please help me understand the meaning of query and let me know if I am wrong at my interpretation .

Comment: Yes. Organizations have different departments which often have no idea what another department is doing. Corporations own corporations which in turn own corporations ... 
Having said that this is a philosophical question which probably is not well suited for SO.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic But goal wise they are connected somewhere. Is not it?
Like Google owns orkut and youtube. But all they are headed to increase the profit of google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a complex organisation with different business units you will have data that is only relevant to the business unit.  Even different types of insurance product (marine, property, public liability) have different information attached to them.  Even if you have an enterprise-wide data warehouse you will still have reporting requirements that are specific to individual departments, even individual users.

Business-wide performance management systems (dashboards etc.) will tend to have a relatively narrow set of dimensional data and metrics common to all the business.  It is quite reasonable to have a narrower set of business-wide performance metrics sliced by a higher level reporting hierarchy for company-wide reporting.  Essentially this is what accounting systems do, although accounts data is by no means the be-all and end-all of management information.

A mature data warehouse system is likely to have a 'board pack', dashboard system or other MIS component where company-wide metrics are reported to senior management.  This will be fairly narrow.  Individual departments will have richer reporting on data that is specific to their operations, but may have little in common with other departments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. This is possible.. Let's take an example of an organization with several Business Units.. Each Business Unit has its own characteristics and Key Performance Indicators.. Therefore, each data mart is distinct on its own.But a C Level executives would like to see the 360 degree of the organization's performance would like to see the target for the overall business goals. There will be the need to connect these datamarts in such cases.

Comment: that  is why i insist to say ," all data marts at least share the final goal of organisation i.e. profit or reputation". So how can the data marts be completely different if seen from top to down?